# Changing SelectionStart in TextChanging handler

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, textbox, uwp

I'm writing a text control with input filtering based on TextBox.

The main idea consists of handling TextChanging event and set correct Text and SelectionStart values.

This worked until Windows 10 Creators Update. Now when I change SelectionStart in TextChanging handler I see correct caret position in UI but next character goes to the old place.

I can not share any code right now but you can reproduce it by adding arbitrary character on each TextChanging call (and setting SelectionStart after this character).

Have Microsoft broken the backward compatibility? Have I done anything wrong?

UPD: So I've found a dirty workaround:

```
async void OnTextChanging(TextBox sender, Text​Box​Text​Changing​Event​Args args)
{
    var newText = HandleText(Text);
    var newSelectionStart = HandleTextDiff(newText, Text);
    Text = newText;

    await Task.Yield();
    SelectionStart = newSelectionStart;
}
```

Task.Yield makes the assignment of SelectionStart to run asynchronously after the control internal assignment.

That's very dirty and ugly because it causes caret blinking in some cases but the only working solution I can find.

Comment: if you're writing a control, just handling TextChanging event may not be enough.

Comment: @LeiYang please, explain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try setting the SelectionLength to 0

Another option might be to use [SetCaretPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648405(VS.85).aspx) Api call

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")] 
static extern bool SetCaretPos(int x, int y);
```

Comment: Setting SelectionLength and SelectionStart is equivalent of TextBox.Select(int, int) call. So it doesn't work.

After TextChanging ends, UI selection is correct but typing selection is broken.